# Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/server.conf:17: ecdh-curve (2.3.10)

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I'm getting line no 17 which is ecdh-curve prime256v1 can anyone help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

> Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/server.conf:17: ecdh-curve (2.3.10)

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
#push "dhcp-option DNS <ip>"
#push "dhcp-option DNS <ip>"
#push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "route <ip> 255.255.255.252"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server
key server
auth S
cipher 
ncp-ciphers 
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Comment: I'm getting line no 17 which is ecdh-curve prime256v1

can anyone help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS (which Linux distribution) are you running this on?

Comment: Are you using the official client: https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/

Comment: im using ubuntu 16.04 @user1686